# Trouble duplicating c string and storing in new character array

Tags: c++, c-strings

We are practicing building our own string functions and I am having trouble figuring out how to properly store my duplicated output into newString. I can print the results I want but how would I store it into newString?

```
void  duplicateString(char newString [], int howManyTotal){
   
    for ( int i = 0; i < howManyTotal* myStrlen(newString); i++){
       
      cout <<  newString[i % myStrlen(newString)];     
}
}
```

Output:

Enter a word: cat

That word has length: 3

cat without vowels is: ct

Enter how many duplicates to make: 3

ctctct

---

"ctctct" is what I'm having trouble with figuring out how to store it into newString

Comment: would strcpy work?

Comment: We are practicing creating are own string functions so i can't use strcpy

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the return type of the function, you can allocate the memory for the string, and assign it using the for loop you created to print the result.

```
char*  duplicateString(char newString [], int howManyTotal){
    char* duplicatedstring = new char[howManyTotal*myStrlen(newString)];
    for ( int i = 0; i < howManyTotal* myStrlen(newString); i++)
       duplicatedstring[i] = newString[i % myStrlen(newString)];
    return duplicatedstring;
}
```

Do not forget to delete[] it after the use!